# __init__() takes exactly 1 argument, MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql

I know questions with the same title have been asked but I cannot figure out the problem based on the solutions given. I am using argparser to connect to database and fetch data. Here

```
import os
import logging
import argparse
import mysql.connector

def main():
    parser = create_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    query_result = get_name_and_id(args.user, args.password, args.host, args.database)

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Require database credentials")
    parser.add_argument("--host", required="True", metavar="[host]", dest='host', help="Database host")
    parser.add_argument("--database-name", required="True", metavar="[database]", dest='database', help="Name of the database to connect to.")
    parser.add_argument("--user-name", metavar="[user]", dest='user', required="True")
    parser.add_argument("--password", required="True", metavar="[password]", dest='password')
    return parser

def get_name_and_id(user,password,host,database):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT id, name FROM some_table")
    cursor.execute(query)
    name_id_list = dict()
    for id, name in cursor:
        name_id_list[id] = name
   return name_id_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

to run this program, I use the command 
`python test_database.py --host somehost --database somedb --user-name myuser-name --password my password`

ANd this is the stacktrace :

> File "test_arg_parsing.py", line 59, in 
>   main()   File "test_arg_parsing.py", line 14, in main
>   query_result = get_name_and_id(args.user, args.password, args.host, args.database)   File "test_arg_parsing.py", line 32, in
>   get_enqueuer_data
>       con = mysql.connector.connect(user, password, host, database)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/**init**.py",
>   line 179, in connect
>       return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py",
>   line 57, in **init**
>       super(MySQLConnection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)

The thing I do not understand here is whether it is complaining about the MySQLConnection **init** function? Or am I not running the right command? I have successfully connected to this same database  using mysql connector. But I want to pass the credentials as arguments now. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `get_name_and_id` function should accept the connection arguments:

```
def get_name_and_id(user, password, host, database):
```

Then, according to the [`connect()` function definition](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/__init__.py#L128), you need to specify *keyword arguments*:

```
def get_name_and_id(user, password, host, database):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=database)
```

---

Or, you can just pass around the arbitrary keyword arguments:

```
def get_name_and_id(**kwargs):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(**kwargs)
    # ...
```

Usage:

```
def main():
    parser = create_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    query_result = get_name_and_id(user=args.user, 
                                   password=args.password, 
                                   host=args.host, 
                                   database=args.database)
```

Comment: My bad I missed the parameters of the function while posting the question. I'll update it.

Comment: I cannot believe I was this careless. Thanks alexce

Comment: @user3527975 I actually find this mysql connector's connect function behavior confusing - why did they make it work with keyword arguments only...Thanks.

Comment: In the second option, you are using args.user, args.password. Args is local to the main method.

Answer (score 2):

These need to be keyword arguments. Try:

```
con = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=database)
```

Comment: Yeah. This is what I was missing. Thanks.